# Where can I find the configuration file for "SuperWebSocket" (Supersocket)? Or how can I change ReceiveBufferSize for websocket in code?

Tags: .net, websocket, configuration-files, supersocket.net

I want to configure the "maxCommandLength" attribute, but I cannot find the configuration file or instructions on how to create it. How can I change ReceiveBufferSize for websocket in code?

Comment: http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6/en-US/Start-SuperSocket-by-Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Use this to change the ReceiveBufferSize:

```
WebSocketServer webServer = new WebSocketServer();
ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig { ReceiveBufferSize = YourWishedSize };

webServer.Setup(config);
```